# Why does my code execute a function defined after the return statement?

Tags: javascript, function

i have this piece of code:

```
(function f(){
    function f(){ return 1; }
    return f();
    function f(){ return 2; }
 })();
```

why does this code print '2'?

Comment: That looks like the typical example from a tutorial or quiz. Where did you find it?

Comment: yeah. question is from book (quiz on js). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, function definition is hoisted to the top of its containing function.

Your function is interpreted by the browser like this:

```
(function f(){
    //Functions defined first
    function f(){ return 1; }
    function f(){ return 2; } //<- Hoisted to top, now this is what f is

    //Now the rest of the code runs
    return f();

 })();
```

Answer (score 6):

Function declarations are hoisted, so both are processed before the `return` statement is evaluated.

The second function overwrites the first because they have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Because functions are hoisted and processed before the return statement, so your last function f() returns 2 and it overwrites the first one.